# how integrate outlook calendar with bizagi?

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, bizagi

In an activity in bizagi, I also need to send an email (resolved), I need to schedule an appointment in the "outlook" calendar. I cannot find how to make this integration, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

my advice is to put such code outside expressions as it can get messy after some time. I would go for C# DLL containing Exchange Web Services (EWS) client, that would create appointment as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/calendars-and-ews-in-exchange.